# How to cachebust css & javascript files smartly?

Tags: dojo, browser-cache

It is an old question to cache well files BUT to be sure that the last version will be served when you updated some modifications on some files. For example it is well know that you can append a get variable like a timestamp to the file uri BUT you lost all cache advantages, the files will NEVER be cached, duh !
For the moment the best way I found trought some web suggestions is :

- add expire infos in the htaccess, ex : ExpiresByType text/javascript
  "access plus 7 days"
- request for fileName+'-'+lastModifTimestamp(src)+fileExtension, ex : 'dir/usualfilename-345678.js'. the lastModifTimestamp is set by
  server script like PHP filemtime($src)
- then in the htaccess, add a rewriterule that rewrite 'dir/usualfilename-2345678.js' to 'dir/usualfilename.js' : `RewriteRule (.+)-[0-9]+(\.(js|css))$ $1$2 [L]`

The advantages is that you never have to change the file names you work with, and even how smartly or weirdly your visitor browser acts, the cache is effective AND you are sure it gets the updated files if modified.

Then in my dojoConfig (dojo 1.7+), I have for example a package wich I like all modules paths been suffixed with the last modif timestamp (my dojo config is written dinamically with PHP). The only way I found is to play with the aliases property : I have to alias all my package's files, the problem is it is quite heavy, then if I have 100 modules in my package, I will need 100 declared aliases even if I require only 3 files...it is not very 'dynamic'. The cachebust property is near but it is for ALL files and it is problematic as explained upper.

My questions are :

1. do you know a better way to manage cache AND updated files as
   mentionned
2. in dojoConfig, is there some smart ways to apply this operation on
   some package files ?

Thank you for any infos !

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished what you are doing two different ways.  I don't think there is a  right answer.  The best answer is what fits your environment.

1) My current gig is developing a product that is well versioned.  So I append the version to the url when requesting css and javascript artifacts.  When a new version is deployed, the end user will get the new files.

2) I also maintain some small websites that don't have a rigorous versioning scheme.  For those, I use the timestamp of when the web server started.  When I deploy new code, it requires a restart of the web server (these aren't high availability sites).  When I deploy updates to the server and restart, the end user will get the new files.

---

EDIT:

Dojo config has a 'cacheBust' property  that you can use.

```
data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, cacheBust: ???, packages: []"
```

where ??? is the version, server timestamp as I previously mentioned.

Comment: thanks for response, 1) yes I use this way and that works perfectly, the difficulty comes when using dojo AMD loader and modules paths, uris & aliases... 2) didn't figure out this solution but at first look, it looks a bit heavy, I prefer far aways the 1st solution as I just have to upload modified files